# Getting authentication to search nearby places using Facebook Graph?

Tags: oauth, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use Facebook's Graph API to get nearby places but when I try https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000 , I get an authentication error. I registered my mobile application on Facebook but I am not sure how to authorize it so that I can search. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the access_token to the GET params you're sending. Also, you can add a q='query' param to search for an exact term like airport or cafe...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000&access_token=2227470867|2.BsVGGHo_rW5YzHPWjk4UMw__.3600.1304935200.0-100001037215362|5jSEZH-iCmFUB7A8myjG98IZVVQ
```